# Is there a way to play background music in python pgzero?

Tags: python, background-music, pgzero

I currently have an audio file in the correct directory but I can't seem to find a command that will play and loop the song. Is it the same as just playing the sound? If not, what is the syntax to play the music?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pygame Zero seems to make this easy. The methods for playing longer music tracks are different than those for playing short sound clips.

If you want to play a music file called `tune1` place it inside a directory below your code file called "music" with the file name `tune1.mp3` or `tune1.ogg`.

Inside your program running the following will play the music on an infinite loop

```
music.play('tune1')
```

References:

- [Build-ins - Music](https://pygame-zero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/builtins.html#music)